# My laravel 8 application was working fine server, but suddently it shows a plain text of the php page in /public/index.php, can you help me

Tags: laravel

My Laravel 8 application was working fine server, but suddenly it shows a plain text of the php page in /public/index.php, can you help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which server are you using? Is it Linux?

Comment: You can try `sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php`

Comment: Hello Jafer! Don't forget to explain the question in more detail, it could help others to help you. Instead of having the images linked as they are right now, maybe you could link them with some text that makes sense and describe what you have tried so far. Hope you find you solution in no time! Welcome to S.O!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP code is not being executed, but the code shows in the browser source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your web server isn't parsing PHP correctly

Check log files, they will probably point you to a misconfigured apache or nginx configuration

There isn't much information in your question, so you're going to get blanket answers